# Spring DataSourceTransactionManager makes saves to fail

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, quartz-scheduler, spring-transactions

I am working on a Spring Boot (2.0.2.RELEASE) application. Recently I enabled transaction management and created a `DataSourceTransactionManager` in the app configuration. We are using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.

I noticed some time later that many (but not all) saves were not actual happening, but all log entries state everything was fine. Only affected saves were made by a Quartz job. Some of them were successful, but most of them not. No errors in the logs.

I since removed the transaction manager and now everything works as expected.
I assume now that DataSourceTransactionManager isn't meant to be used with JPA or Hibernate. I still don't know what to use and why this error happened.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The correct `PlatformTransactionManager` implementation to use with applications that use a single `EntityManagerFactory` is [`JpaTransactionManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaTransactionManager.html).

Comment: @manish thank you! How can I make sure I use a single `EntityManagerFactory` ?

Comment: Spring Boot uses one `EntityManagerFactory` per data source (database). Check the number of data sources configured for the application through either `application.properties` or Java config.